# Magnify.js with bxSlider

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider, magnify

I'm trying to implement [Magnify.js](http://thdoan.github.io/magnify/) to a [bxSlider](http://bxslider.com/) slide but I have a problem, the zoom effect just works on the very first image of the slide, once I move to the next one the effect won't work, but it does on the first one. All of the slide's images have a "zoom" id which I'm targeting with **Magnify**.
**Is there any way to make it work for the whole slide instead of just the first one?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the follow snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/L9fe0py3/5/

HTML:

```
<ul class="bxslider">
  <li><img id="img1" src="http://bxslider.com/images/home_slides/picto.png" data-magnify-src="http://bxslider.com/images/home_slides/picto.png" /></li>
  <li><img id="img2" src="http://bxslider.com/images/home_slides/houses.jpg" data-magnify-src="http://bxslider.com/images/home_slides/houses.jpg"/></li>
  <li><img id="img3" src="http://bxslider.com/images/home_slides/hillside.jpg" data-magnify-src="http://bxslider.com/images/home_slides/hillside.jpg"/></li>
</ul>
<img id="img4" src="http://bxslider.com/images/home_slides/hillside.jpg" data-magnify-src="http://bxslider.com/images/home_slides/hillside.jpg"/>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
      onSlideAfter:function(e){
        $(e).find('img').magnify();
      }
    });
    $('#img1,#img2,#img3,#img4').magnify();
});
```

You need to replace the "data-magnify-src" attribute on the `<img/>` elements to the "big" image URL, and ALSO (EDITED) add the .magnify() function everytime a slide changes.

Comment: Nope, this didn't work at all. In your code it only works on the first one, which is the problem that I have.

Comment: Just fixed it for you :D